# stocklist Dynagrid demo

Tags: javascript, html, lightstreamer

I'm trying to modify the stocklist Dynagrid demo which is designed to work with HTML5 and Javascript, it's originally designed to subscribe an item per subscription.

In my case, I have connected this demo to my lightstreamer server, the adapter in my server deals with itemgroub and fieldschema instead of itemList and fieldList which was used in the example.

I modified the code to subscribe using this item group and equivalent field schema, now the dynagrid listener (onVisualUpdate function) is capable to detect how many items in the item group and based on that it creates the equivalent number of rows, however, when I call getChangedFieldValue for and one of the fields in the dynagrid, I get null always, and based of that no data is updated on the screen.

What is the solution for this problem, and how can I get the updated values?

(Note: Currently, I get the data directly from the info paramter which is passed to onVisualUpdate function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Field Schema, fields in the subscription are identified by their 1-based index within the schema and not by their name. So, wen you call getChangedFieldValue try to use the 1-based index to identify a field.